# Lyx time out exporting latexpdf

Tags: lyx, miktex

I have installed Lyx recently. I was able to create a pdf file earlier, but it was giving errors like article.cls file does not exist. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled MikTeX and installed a lot of packages on MikTeX using Admin console. Now, in Lyx it is not giving any error. I have created a document in Lyx. I want the pdf version. If I am exporting as text file or word doc, it's exporting perfectly, but when exporting as pdflatex, it's giving timeout. Please help how to resolve this issue.

I can see following log

```
21:16:18.405: Exporting ...
21:16:18.445: (buffer-export-as)
21:16:18.476: pdflatex  "newfile5.tex"
21:16:19.682: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 
2.9.7380 64-bit)
21:18:39.076: Automatic save done.support\FileName.cpp (273): Could 
not move file 
C:/xxxxxxxLocal/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.DYaYdLOM7176/lyxautoHp7176.lyx to 
C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/#newfile5.lyx#
21:20:44.524: Automatic save done.
21:23:39.085: Automatic save done.
21:25:44.537: Automatic save done.
21:28:39.088: Automatic save done.support\Systemcall.cpp (268): 
Systemcall: 'pdflatex  "newfile5.tex"' did not finish!
support\Systemcall.cpp (269): error The process timed out. It might 
be restarted automatically.
support\Systemcall.cpp (270): status The process exited normally.
Error: LaTeX failed
----------------------------------------
The external program
pdflatex 
finished with an error. It is recommended you fix the cause of the 
external program's error (check the logs). 
21:29:02.481: Error while exporting format: pdf2 
C:/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/cc.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled and installed Lyx again. It's again giving error document class article.cls is not found. But it is able to create the pdflatex documents. So going ahead with ignoring the frequent error, as it is serving my purpose.